# Translation for instant params

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I am using ngx-translate and have no problem with translating strings values in HTML components, but how can I translate something like this:

```
  <input matInput tabindex="-1" required placeholder="{{j == 0 ? ('Where') : ( j == passatControlGroup.controls.length - 1 ? 'Time' : 'Via')}}"
```

My translation is in JSON file and I would like to make it with key:value, as I made for HTML strings.

```
<mat-icon>{{'passatCarComponent.Clear'|translate}}</mat-icon>
```

What is syntax to translate ('Where'), if I want to wirte it to JSON file as:

```
{
"passatCarComponent": "translation for Where"
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wanting to translate the `Where`, `Time`, and `Via` text in your `placeholder` attribute, you'll need to:

- change the text to the name of the key for the translation
- add those keys and translations to your translation file
- add the `translate` pipe in your `placeholder` attribute `{{ ... }}` logic

Your template would look something like this:

```html
<input matInput tabindex="-1" required placeholder="{{ (j == 0 ? ('passatCarComponent.Where') : ( j == passatControlGroup.controls.length - 1 ? 'passatCarComponent.Time' : 'passatCarComponent.Via')) | translate }}">
```

Comment: Thank you, it is working. I was told, that I should use $translate.instant and was a bit confused :)